# Custom Angular Library Import multiple Modules not barrel

Tags: angular, yeoman-generator

Hi I am trying to build a custom Angular Library. Using yeoman-generator ([link](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)) I get a template to build upon, that works just fine. The problem is that it uses a (not anymore best practice) barrel `index.ts`, and what I want is to be able to have one module per component and import accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone faces the same problem, here is how my files are now structured and connected:

I have a component with the desired functionality `HelloWorld`

Then a module for this component:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HelloWorld } from './hello-world.component';

export * from './hello-world.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HelloWorld,
  ],
  exports: [
    HelloWorld,
  ]
})
export class HelloWorldModule {}
```

And finally inside the `index.ts` file is only this line:

```
export * from './hello-world.module';
```

To use in the projects the `app.module.ts` import is:

```
import { HelloWorldModule } from 'test-lib'
```

and also add `HelloWorldModule` to the imports array.